# Inserting an OpenGL layer in front of a UIView with controls

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to use OpenGLES animation layer in front of a UIView which contains controls. For example, I want to render animation in FRONT of the UIButton (so animated objects pass in front of (occluding) the button from view as they pass).

Haven't been able to find an answer despite several related threads.

My primary view controller has one view in it, of type GLKView. I have a separate xib (View.xib) which contains one UIView with one UIButton in it.

**Within my viewDidLoad, I have:**

```
self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

if (!self.context) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
}

GLKView *glView = (GLKView *)self.view;
glView.context = self.context;
glView.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGB565;
glView.opaque = NO;
glView.alpha = 1.0;
glView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView *controlView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
controlView.frame = CGRectMake(100,200,100,100);

controlView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
controlView.alpha = 1;
controlView.opaque = YES;

CALayer *controlViewLayer = controlView.layer;
[controlViewLayer insertSublayer:glView.layer above:controlViewLayer];

[self setupGL];
```

Within **drawInRect** I have:
 glClearColor(0,0,0,0);

The result is that my GLKView animation renders with a black/clear background, but I cannot see my UIView containing the button.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Is your EaglLayer also set to opaque = NO?

Comment: I verified glView.layer.opaque = NO;
However, that made no difference...I still see the animation but nothing else...

Comment: What's up with controlView.opaque = YES, and then your glView.layer is inserted in that view's layer?

Comment: Actually, good call. I change the last portion of viewDidLoad to be as follows, and the Button view (controlViewLayer) appears. However, it appears in front of animation layer, irrespective of whether I choose to insert it above or below the glView:

    controlView.frame = CGRectMake(100,200,100,100);
    controlView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    controlView.alpha = 1.0;
    controlView.opaque = NO;
    
    CALayer *controlViewLayer = controlView.layer;
    [glView.layer insertSublayer:controlViewLayer below:self.view.layer];

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw another question talking about that one in the last day or so (problems in layers relative to the animation layer)

Comment: Yes, I think i've seen that and some others even...except don't recall seeing any with an actual solution unfortunately. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work. The issue was that elsewhere in my GL Code (actually it was the sample XCode project provided by 71Squared for Particle Emitter in standard XCode projects), there was a call in ES1Renderer.m for glClearColor. That call included an alpha value of 1.0f. As soon as I set that to 0.0f (like elsewhere in the code), the front (EAGLView) layer became transparent as expected.